# How to use custom listOf in QuickCheck

Tags: haskell

In my code, I need to generate a list of `Point`

I've instanced the custom type `Point` in the `Arbitrary` Type Class.
So far so good.

Now I need to generate a list:  `[Points]`

But the default random list generated by QuickCheck(using `listOf` I believe?) is not working for me. 
Because I need some special relations between the `points`. I know of the Generator combinators, ex. `suchAs` But they are too slow(because of very rare relation)

I've defined a customed `Gen [Point]` to suit my needs.

```
randomBoard :: Gen [Point]
randomBoard = ...
```

But I have no idea how to let my test to use this custom `Gen` in the property test because it defaults to the `listOf` generated list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, the issue is that your tests are using `Arbitrary` instances, by way of the `Testable` [instance for](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.13.2/docs/Test-QuickCheck.html#t:Testable) `(Arbitrary a, Show a, Testable prop) => Testable (a -> prop)`.

A common pattern to get custom generators is to throw around some `newtype`s with the desired `Arbitrary` instances. So you'd define something like

```
newtype Board = Board [Point]

instance Arbitrary Board where
  ...
```

That would work. But I'd recommend bypassing `Arbitrary` altogether and writing your properties with `forAll` [and its variants](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.13.2/docs/Test-QuickCheck.html#v:forAll).

```
genBoard :: Gen [Point]
genBoard = ...

shrinkBoard :: [Point] -> [[Point]]
shrinkBoard = ...

myProperty :: Property
myProperty = forAllShrink genBoard shrinkBoard (\board -> ...)
```